# Programatically listing and sending requests to dynamic App Engine instances

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to send a particular HTTP request (or otherwise communicate a message) to every (dynamic/autoscaled) instance which is currently running for a particular App Engine application.

My goal is to trigger each instance to discard some locally cached data (because I have just modified the underlying data and want them to reload it).

One possible solution is to store a value in Memcache, and have instances check this each time they handle a request to see if they should flush their cache. But this adds latency to every request.

Another possible solution would be to somehow stop all running instances. No fixed overhead, but some impact while instances are restarted.

An even less desirable solution would be to redeploy the application code in order to cause all instances to be stopped. This now adds additional delay on my end as a deployment takes some time.

Comment: I don't think there's any API currently to do so, but you could have each one append to a list in memcache as it starts up so you can track them all.

Comment: hi, please have a look at the following docs, it treats the topic how to call a dedicated instance https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-requests-are-routed

Comment: **Technomage** - As mentioned in another comment, it looks like the shutdown hook is not invoked for autoscaled instances, so while I could have them register themselves on startup, I currently have no way from them to un-register themselves when they are shutdown.

**Michael** - These are dynamic (autoscaled) instances, so I don't think URL-based routing will be able to address specific instances.

Comment: @CAW not directly an answer, but google REST APIs can list running instances and let you stop them. To alleviate the warm up time, you might introduce warm-up request (not sure they apply to automatic scaling) and/or shut them down gradually.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the management API to [list instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions.instances/list) for a given version, but I'd suggest that you'd probably want to use something like the PubSub API to [create a subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber) on each of your App Engine instances. Since each instance has its own subscription, any messages sent to the monitored queue will be received by all instances.

You can create the subscription at startup ([the `/_ah/start` endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#startup) may be useful), and then delete it at shutdown (using the [`/_ah/stop` endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#shutdown)).

Comment: Pub/Sub looks promising. But I'm having a problem where it appears that the shutdown hook (registered via LifecycleManager.getInstance().setShutdownHook) is never invoked.
 
I'm using autoscaled instances. To test, I added a one-line shutdown hook which just creates a datastore entity with a specific key. After causing instance shutdown via the console, or by deploying a new version of the app, I can see that the datastore entity is never created.

Comment: It has also just occurred to me that it does not appear to be possible to address specific autoscale instances via URL, so I cannot register an endpoint for each of them for a Pub/Sub Push subscription.

A Pull subscription is also problematic. I would have to poll pub/sub before handling every incoming request (adding latency to each request is not at all desirable). Or perhaps spread this out by polling only every Nth request (but this means stale data would continue to be user for some time).

Really a proper "push" of some kind is best, but I fear may be impossible with autoscaling?

Comment: I *believe* you can use the instance ID from [the modules API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/using-the-modules-api) for routing requests to an autoscaled instance.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. The modules API returns a long alphanumeric ID for all of my autoscaled instances (79 characters in length), and since the maximum length of a subdomain name is 64 characters it's not even possible to address them using this ID.

For manually scaled instances it returns a short numerical ID, so this isn't a problem.

Comment: Pub/Sub would work if each instance created a unique subscription and then did a blocking pull in the background (I'm in golang so a go routine). As new instances come online, they get unique subscriptions (use a counter in the datastore). The subscriptions could be set to expire after a short time as well as the message. If the cleanup from expiry is too long after the instance shuts down, you could also schedule a cron task to delete old subscriptions.